# Right transimpedence amplifier choice for input range

Tags: board, transimpedance, precision, transimpedance-amplifier, leakage

I have a device that produces a ±30 nA signal and I'd like to measure this to a 0.1 nA precision.

Since the currents are so low and I don't have much time to make mistakes, I am planning to use a TIA embedded in an evaluation board.

Will this do the job?

[EVAL-ADA4622-2ARZ](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/user-guides/eval-ada4622-2arz-ug-1818.pdf)

If not, how do I search for something that will work? I don't seem to be finding the things on the datasheets that I was expecting I would.

My plan is to first interface this with an ADC.

Comment: What bandwidth? What is the current source? Keep in mind you generally want to have the absolute minimum capacitance on the input to a TIA, so cabling must be kept to a minimum.

Comment: JoVi, when you write plus-or-minus, do you really mean that? Do you need two quadrants of operation?

Comment: To use that eval board, you need to change the feedback resistor to create a TIA. Feedback resistor calculation: Rf = Vadc/Imax. If your ADC input voltage range is 3V, then your feedback resistor will be 100M. Getting a circuit to work with resistances in this range is difficult. See my adventures here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/644934/sensitive-transimpedance-amplifier-oscillates

Answer (score 1):

The best op-amp selection will depend on where the signal current (+/-30nA) originates from, and where it is going.  The best case is that this current is passing through a resistor with one end tied to 0V (ground) of the op-amp circuit.  This means the signal produced by this current is with-respect-to (wrt) ground, which is always easier to process than if it was wrt some other voltage (such as the positive or negative power supply rail).

Let's proceed based on the signal to be captured is wrt 0V.  Now select a resistor to convert this current to a voltage.  This is where bandwidth and response time become important.  A large value resistor will give plenty of signal voltage but will cause low bandwidth and slow step response.  Ideally, the capacitance in parallel with the resistor should be zero, but in practice it can never be zero, it will be dependent upon various factors including:

1. the quality of the resistor,
2. the quality of the PCB materials and the PCB layout,
3. whatever else is connected to signal end of the resistor.

As a rough guide, allow about 10pF of "parasitic" capacitance here - even though you may not have any intentional capacitance here, that is what you will have on a good PCB with good materials and a good layout.  Trying to get the parasitic capacitance lower than this is quite difficult.

To convert 30mA to 3.0V means a resistor of 100 Meg-Ohms.  A 100 Meg-Ohm resistor in parallel with 10pF has an RC time constant of 1milli-second.  Is that fast enough for your application?  If "yes" then the next question is: is the +/-30nA signal adversely affected by driving into a voltage that varies from -3V to +3V?

If the answer is "no" then all you need is a 100Mohm resistor in series with the signal current, with one end connected to GROUND, and the other end being the signal that you connect to a simple op-amp buffer (to ensure the ADC does not put any extra capacitance or resistance on the signal).

However, this buffer does need some thinking.  You mentioned that the precision required is better than 0.1nA.  That impacts the DC accuracy of the op-amp in two ways:

1. Input offset voltage.  Assuming the opamp is to be configured as a non-inverting buffer, the output offset voltage will be the same as that of the input offset voltage (since the gain is 1).  0.1nA * 100Mohm = 10mV.  So input offset of the opamp must be less than 10mV, say, less than 5mV to be safe.
2. Input bias current. The current from the signal to the input pin of the op-amp must be less than 0.1nA, say half this value so 50pA, across the full range of voltage swing (-3V to 0V to +3V).

Considering both of the requirements above, many op-amps should be suitable, particularly if bandwidth is limited to ~10kHz.  For example, the OPA2916 will suit this, since it has the following typical values:
Vio = 0.025mV
Ib  = +/-5pA
Bandwidth = 2.5MHz in unity-gain buffer configuration.
Refer:
https://www.ti.com/product/OPA2196

**Let's Review The Assumptions**

Note: The above is offered only if the three (3) main assumptions are true; to recap, these assumptions were:

1. The signal is wrt gnd.
2. The +/-30nA signal is **NOT** adversely affected by driving into a voltage that varies from -3V to +3V.
3. The time-constant of 1ms is fast enough.

Here is what you may have to consider if these assumptions are not true:

**Assumption 1:**
If the signal is wrt to some other node, then there are several ways to address this.  The most obvious way is to have a good op-amp that can remove the common-mode signal.  There are special op-amps designed to do this task very well, intended for measuring current, however, the signal range you have specified is quite low and it may be quite challenging to find a suitable op-amp.  Try the current-sense amplifiers from TI:
https://www.ti.com/amplifier-circuit/current-sense/overview.html

Note that these current sensing solutions may have limited bandwidth, so choose carefully.

The other way to address this is to translate a good-quality copy of the signal to a new path that is referenced to ground.  This can be done using a circuit known as "precision current mirror", there are many references to such circuits in various app notes, here is a good starting point:
https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADL5315.pdf

**Assumption 2:**
If the signal is affected by the changing voltage, then there are two main methods to address this.  Method 1 is to have the signal operate into a constant load voltage, and mirror the current into a new path - note that this is the same as the second solution mentioned above, so this can solve both these problems.

Method 2 is to reduce the voltage swing by making the current-to-voltage converting resistor smaller.  Of course, this now means that the op-amp must amplify the signal to get the full output voltage needed at the ADC input.

**Assumption 3:**
If you need faster response time, then you may have to apply the same solutions again.  By keeping the voltage swing that the 30nA current source experiences "small", the effect of the parasitic capacitance is reduced.  Using a current mirror will improve bandwidth, provided that the current mirror itself is not adversely affected by signal voltage swing at its output terminals.

You may have to reduce the gain of the first-stage (the current-to-voltage converter, the 100Mohm resistor) & increase the gain of the second stage (the op-amp).